# Finding maximum number of votes to a person per state

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table called votes

```
vid     stateid     voterid     voteeid
 1         1           1           1
 2         1           2           1
 3         1           3           1
 4         1           4           1
 5         1           5           2
 6         1           6           2
 7         2           7           3
 8         2           8           3
 9         2           9           4
```

I want to find the maximum number of votes to a person per state.

```
Select Top 1 voteeid from votes where stateid = 1 group by voteeid order by count(voteeid) desc
```

This query is capable of finding maximum number of votes to a person in a single state.

I want to find maximum number votes to a person in every state. In short I want a output like this

```
votes     voteeid
 4            1
 2            3
```

Can some one point me in a right direction ?

Thanks

Comment: myabe use 2 group by, one for stateid, and one for voteid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `group by` to find the number of votes per state, and use `rank` to select all top votee's:

```
select  stateid
,       voteeid
,       votes
from    (
        select  stateid
        ,       voteeid
        ,       count(*) as votes
        ,       rank() over (partition by stateid order by count(*) desc) 
                    as rn
        from    @votes
        group by
                stateid
        ,       voteeid
        ) cnt
where   rn = 1
```

Use `row_number` instead of `rank` if you don't want ties.

For MySQL, you can't use ranking functions, so you have to add an additional query to find the maximum vote per state:

```
select  cnt.stateid
,       cnt.voteeid
,       cnt.votes
from    (
        select  stateid
        ,       voteeid
        ,       count(*) as votes
        from    @votes
        group by
                stateid
        ,       voteeid
        ) cnt
join    (
        select  stateid
        ,       max(votes) as maxvotes
        from    (
                select  stateid
                ,       voteeid
                ,       count(*) as votes
                from    @votes
                group by
                        stateid
                ,       voteeid
                ) cnt2
        group by
                stateid
        ) filter_max
on      filter_max.stateid = cnt.stateid
        and filter_max.maxvotes = cnt.votes
```

[Example on SO Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/98590/)

Comment: I don't think MySql supports the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, does it?

Comment: @Daniel Renshaw: Yeah I noticed the MySQL too late.  Updated the answer to something that should run on MySQL.

Comment: I am so sorry. I am using `mssql` sorry for the wrong tag. I don't know how I selected `mysql` instead of `mssql`. Can you please roll back your answer.

Comment: @Searock: Okay, now both versions are in the answer